# How to detect overwrite event in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure that I don't know that is action called. So here is explanation.

1. User type into `<input type="text">` as "12345"
2. User drag to highlight all the value `12345`
3. User type "6" to replace all the data from "12345" to "6"

The `keydown` event wasn't help. The event only hold that key that get press. Even if using `keydown` and `keyup` to comparing is seem to be work but it's too late because I want to use `preventDefault` to prevent the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent highlighting and replacing, just check that `e.target.selectionStart === e.target.selectionEnd`:

```js
document.getElementById("phone").addEventListener("beforeinput", function(e) {
    if(e.target.selectionStart !== e.target.selectionEnd) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
    return;
});
```

```html
<input id="phone">
```

Or in general, if you want to compare the previous value to the next value and make some decision based off of that, you'd want to do something roughly like this (where deleting needs a little polishing but for the most part):

```js
document.getElementById("phone").addEventListener("beforeinput", function(e) {
    
    let nextVal = 
      e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.selectionStart) +
      (e.data ?? '') +
      e.target.value.substring(e.target.selectionStart + (e.data ? e.data.length : 0), e.target.selectionEnd)
    ;
    if (e.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward') nextVal = nextVal.substring(0, nextVal.length - 1)
    const prevVal = e.target.value;
    console.log({nextVal, prevVal});
    return;
});
```

```html
<input id="phone">
```

Comment: I never though about `beforeinput` before, very much thanks.